# DailyFileRolling without log4j & logback

Tags: java, java-8

I am looking for a simple daily file rolling utility that will `create file` with the current `date` in `<filename>-yyyy-mm-dd.txt` 
and will continue to write on it and when the `date` changes,
it will `create a new file` & `continue` to write on it.

On googling most of the result I got was using `logback or log4j`.

Is there any way to get daily file roller available in java `without` **logback or log4j**?

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6350749

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about `java.util.logging` - you will have to implement your own `java.util.logging.Handler`.

I haven't tried this myself but take a look at `Tomcat`s `JULI` package, they've implemented a `Handler` that should be able to do rolling-file logging. The class is `org.apache.juli.FileHandler` and can be found on [maven central](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/9.0.0.M4/tomcat-juli-9.0.0.M4-sources.jar) (version 9.0.0M4).

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest I've done is extending a Writer and using a date format. It should be optimized to open file only when needed , but it works.

```
public class StackOverflowFileRolling extends Writer {
  String baseFilePath;
  String datePattern;

  public StackOverflowFileRolling (String baseFilePath, String datePattern) {
    super();
    this.baseFilePath = baseFilePath;
    this.datePattern = datePattern;
  }

  @Override
  public void write (char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    String name = baseFilePath + new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).format(new Date()) + ".log";
    File file = new File(name);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
      fileWriter.write(cbuf, off, len);
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void flush () throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void close () throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

Then use it by wrapping it in a printWriter

```
try (
    PrintWriter logger = new PrintWriter(
        new StackOverflowFileRolling("/var/log/stackoverflowfilerolling", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    ) {
  //this will append 2 lines in the log, since the FileWriter is in append mode
  logger.println("test");
  logger.println("test2");
}
```

EDIT some improvements to create directories and use a PrintWriter

Comment: I am looking something simpler like this. But in your case it will continue to write on the same file even if the date changes. Can you explain a bit more on the file optimization? The simplest implementation I can think of is before writing check if the file exists if not create a new file and then write to it. This will be terrible for performance as I have to check each time before writing.

Comment: No when the date changes the file name changes and we write on another file. As is said it works and i use it like that. I just think that a market framework would try to keep the file opened, and close it when the date change, or after a timeout. What i do is open and close the file for every line we write. The close() is done with the "try(Closeable)" introduced in Java7. EDIT: See the line String name = baseFilePath + new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).format(new Date()) + ".log";
    it is evaluated each time and will change it's value, because of the new Date()